# Daily limit on how many gifts you can collect from pokestops?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a limit for how many gifts you can collect from pokestops?
I have over 100 friends and it seems like there is a limit how many gifts I can collect from pokestops. For the last 100 pokestops I have not received any gifts?

I'm not talking about the limit on 10 gifts in your inventory or the limit on opening 20 gifts received.
I collect ten gifts. Send them to friends. Collect another ten. Send them, etc. But when I was around 100 gifts sent I didn't get any more gifts at the pokestops. Just unluck or a limit?

Answer (score 4):

The [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/8sxfft/max_gifts_obtainable_from_stopsgyms_per_day_100/) community has been experiencing this as well. Aside from the reddit thread, I was unable to find any other articles that is talking about this.

Despite there being an appearance of receiving gifts from Pokéstops being capped at 100 per day, I have confirmed there is no daily limit. I reached out to Niantic's support team and below is a response I received earlier today.

> Hello Trainer,
>
> Thank you for contacting Pokémon GO support.
>
> Good question!
>
> **There are no limits to the number of gifts you can get from a Pokéstop per day.**
>
> However, you will be able to open only 20 Gifts per day.
>
> Keep playing Pokémon GO and I would be happy to help if there is anything else.

<sub>(emphasis my own)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can send 1 gift to each friend. However, Only 100 friends can get a gift. Once you reach that limit you will not receive gifts from pokemon stops/gyms. If you plan it right, Such as I sent 90 out, I can still collect 40, which allows me to reach over that limit. You can also receive 5 gifts from your buddy pokemon twice a day. This than makes it where you can send out 140, if you play it right.  The pokemon bag allows you to hold 40, and you at this time can open 30.